# convergence of series implies convergence of coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Is it true that

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{i_n} y^i \rightarrow \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{i} y^i \quad \forall y \in [0,1]$$

implies

$$a_{i_n} \to_{n \to \infty} a_{i} \quad \forall i$$

where $0 \leq a_i,a_{i_n} \leq 1$ for all $i,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{i_n} = 1 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

---

Choosing $y = 0$ immediately gives $a_{0_n} \to_{n \to \infty} a_{0}$

---

My idea (please help for correctness and rigorousness):

$$\operatorname{lim}_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{i_n} y^i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{i} y^i \quad \forall y \in [0,1]$$

Since the series of coefficients converges and dominates this power series for all $y\in [0,1]$ we have

$$\implies \sum_{i=0}^\infty \operatorname{lim}_{n\to\infty} a_{i_n} y^i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{i} y^i \quad \forall y \in [0,1]$$

Two power series are equal iff all coefficients are equal, thus we have:

$$\implies \operatorname{lim}_{n\to\infty} a_{i_n} = a_i$$

as desired.

**Is the above argument valid?**

Comment: Stating it differently: We have $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (a_{i_n} - a_i)y^i \to 0 \quad \forall y \in [0,1]$. Can I somehow swap lim and sum with help of a congergent majorant and then conclude that the coefficients need to converge?

Comment: If you use dominated convergence, then you're saying that the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits, but this is supposing beforehand that said limits exist. When you "switch limit and sum" in your proof, it's entirely possible (without further argument) that the symbol $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_{i_{n}}$ is nothing more than notation manipulation, with no meaning behind it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to show this is to consider orthogonal polynomials on $[0,1].$ Let $f_{n}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i_{n}}y^{i},$ for all $n\geq1$ and let $f=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i}y^{i}.$ If we let $\{p_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a collection of polynomials with $\mathrm{deg}(p_{n})=n$ for all $n\geq0,$ with the property that $$\langle p_{n},p_{m}\rangle=\int_{0}^{1}p_{n}(x)p_{m}(x)\mathrm{d}x=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }n=m\\0&\text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$$ then we have that if $g(y)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_{i}p_{i},$ we can cover the coefficients by $\langle g,p_{i}\rangle=b_{i},$ for all $i\geq0,$ and these maps are continuous. Since $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ pointwise, and since the $f_{n}$ and $f$ are continuous and bounded (so that we don't have to worry about these integrals being finite), we have $\langle f_{n},p_{i}\rangle\rightarrow\langle f,p_{i}\rangle$ for all $i\geq0.$

Now the important thing is that if $g(y)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i}y^{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_{i}p_{i},$ then $b_{i}=\sum_{j=0}^{i}c_{i,j}a_{j}$ for some constants $c_{i,j}$ which do not depend on $g,$ and this allows us to recover the $a_{i}$ coefficients from the $b_{i}$ coefficients. In short, in your problem above, the convergence of the $b_{i}$ (the $\langle f_{n},p_{i}\rangle$) implies the convergence of the $a_{i}$ (your $a_{i_{n}}$), which you could show by a strong induction on $i$, if you wanted to show all of the details ($b_{0}=c_{0,0}a_{0}$ where $c_{0,0}\neq0,$ so convergence of $b_{0}$ and $a_{0}$ are equivalent, and then $b_{1}=c_{1,0}a_{0}+c_{1,1}a_{1},$ where $c_{1,1}\neq0,$ so since $a_{0}$ and $b_{1}$ converge, $a_{1}$ converges, and so on).